# JsFiddle Javascript not firing?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I've got a huge feeling I'm simply being idiotic here, but is it me or is Js not firing in JsFiddle?

I built this snippet here but can't seem to get it to fire. Im probably missing something super obvious, but would be grateful for any assistance.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="col">

    <h3 class="txt spacer">Dynamic input, based on select value...</h3>
    <input type="text" name="field-one" class="txt stretch" />

    <div class="boxes">
      <input type="checkbox" id="box-2" onChange="myFunction()" checked>
      <label for="box-2">Apply a name?</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction() {
  // Text field element.
  var a = document.getElementByName('field-one');
  // Checkbox element.
  var b = document.getElementById('box-2');

  if (b.checked) {
    a.disabled = false;
    a.placeholder = 'Not Applicable';
    alert('Checkbox State Changed.');
  } else {
    a.disabled = true;
    a.placeholder = 'Enter Your Full Name';
    alert('Checkbox State Changed.');
  }
}
```

> **[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/1g0bfv2L/24/)**

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Regards,

-B.

**EDIT**

> I'm an idiot. Thanks guys.

Comment: Have to set *Load Type* in dropdown. Default is to wrap all code in a load event handler and it isn't global then.

Comment: ` <input type="checkbox" id="box-2" onChange="myFunction()" checked>` should be onchange not onChange.

Comment: @JayBuckman I thought camel case succeded, could you elaborate why it would be a dis-advantage to use `onChange` rather than `onchange`?

Comment: As the @Curl said - you have to change load level or use window.funcName. Here is you working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1g0bfv2L/39/

Comment: @Beaniie - I always use the lowercase versions as that's what VS generates and what references like MDN use.  As a C/C++/C#/JavaScript programmer, I'm case-sensitive.  And I really hate finding out I've spent an hour debugging something that was caused by careless casing.  But looking at the examples on MDN, I see lots of camel casing.  So, I'd say go with whatever you feel comfortable with...

Comment: @JayBuckman understandable, I can see why you prefer it. I too would be frustated by this. Being just a humble web dev, for now it's a bad habit I think I can live with. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things here, it should be `document.getElementsByTagName` (plural) and you need to change the settings, that will embed the JS code in before the body closes.

```
var a = document.getElementsByName('field-one')[0];
```

I am using `[0]` here to access the very first element of the array as `document.getElementsByName()` will return you an array of elements if encountered multiple matching elements. If you want to select a specific one, make sure you select the DOM element in a more specific way.

And change the **Load Type** to

> No wrap - in `<body>` (`<head>` will work as well)

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/1g0bfv2L/30/)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance & the descriptive answer. Supurb. I'll mark as correct soon.

Answer (score 3):

The Javascript Load Type for your jsFiddle is set to `onLoad`. This will nest your `myFunction` function, and therefore won't be available in the global scope.

You can either change the Load Type, or set the variable on the `window`:

```
window.myFunction = function()....
```

---

NB: You then receive another error for `getElementByName`. This isn't a function of `document`. You're probably looking for `getElementsByName`.

Answer (score 2):

Open the DevTools and you'll see

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange ((index):192)
```

Now why isn't the function defined? Perhaps it's not defined at the right spot?

Look at where you load your JavaScript and change it to:
[image]

Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1g0bfv2L/28/). Note that I fixed a typo on line 3 `getElementsByName`.

Answer (score 1):

First, set your `seeting` of javascript `LOAD TYPE` to `head`.

last, is `getElementsByName` not `getElementByName` and it would return array so you need to parse.

```
let a = document.getElementsByName('field-one')[0];
```

hope it's helpful.